# Rent a Car in Constanta Airport with return in another country

Tags: airport-transfer, car-rentals, taxis, romania, bulgaria

Is there any means to rent a car in Constanta (RO) for one day and the return to be in another city, like Dobrich, BG or Varna BG?

Is a private transport (taxi) a better alternative to go from Constanta airport (RO) to Dobrich (BG) as the distance is not so far?

Comment: You should be able to, but probably will have to negotiate with the car hire company. Might be work calling them up before you get there to sort it out?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of renting a car (which will be very expensive) you can take a bus.

Take a look here for the bus schedules: http://www.autogari.ro/Transport/Constanta-VarnaBG?lang=en

If the page doesn't show in English, then select English from the dropdown at the top of the page.  Enjoy!  Varna is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it's not possible to rent a car at the airport and drop it in Dobrich because only SIXT and AVIS offer car rentals at the airport but none of them has office in Dobrich. IMHO your only chance is a taxi or private transfer. There is a [Bulgarian company](http://besttaxitransfer.com/category/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0-en/?lang=en) that offers transfers from Constanta Airport to some Bulgarian Black Sea resorts - I assume that it should be possible to bring you to Dobrich, but you better call them and ask.

Answer (score 1):

Renting a car from one country and dropping it off in another is generally allowed by major companies such as Europcar, Sixt, etc. From [Europcar's FAQ page](http://www.europcar.ie/EBE/module/render/faq/returning-the-vehicle#10):

> "If you want to return the vehicle to different station from the station where you start your rental, [...] **Domestic one ways are generally possible** inside the same country between all stations, except between mainland and islands and vice-versa. **Europcar operates** a large network of international key cities **in order to allow flexible cross border travelling**. In smaller locations you will be required to pay a higher price."

The only thing is the prohibitive cost this will have, as you will effectively be billed for repatriating the car. So do call your agency in advance and check if this is an option for them, and for you in terms of viability.

I don't know about taxis between the two cities, as I am not a local. But you might want to check the cost and availability of local trains/coaches. I bet that will be cheaper than an international car-rental drop-off.